# Finding the biggest and smallest number with only with exactly three IF statements(no else)

Tags: c#

Firstly thank you for showing interest in my question, right now I'm in my first year of being an IT assistant and this question was in our book but nobody out of my class seems to be able to find a solution for it. We aren't allowed to use any else statements or arrays.

This was my (not working) piece of code:

```
double n1, n2, n3, biggest, smallest;
Console.Write("First number:  ");
n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Second number: ");
n2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Third number: ");
n3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (n1 < n2 && n2 < n3)
{
    smallest = n3;
    biggest = n1;
}
if (n2 < n3 && n3 < n1)
{
    smallest = n1;
    biggest = n2;
}
if (n3 < n1 && n1 < n2)
{
    smallest = n2;
    biggest = n3;
}
Console.WriteLine("\tMax: {0}", biggest);
Console.WriteLine("\tMin: {0}", smallest);
```

Comment: Hint: Exploit the fact that you can also compare against `smallest` and `biggest` once they got some value assigned.

Comment: Searching a bit on the net you can find this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-of-three-integers-without-comparison-operators/#:~:text=Let%203%20input%20numbers%20be%20x%2C%20y%20and,terminates%2C%20c%20will%20hold%20the%20minimum%20of%203. From there you can just use a variable starting from 0 and incrementing it inside a loop until the variable is bigger than your numbers. Then you return the counter decremented. No if at all

Comment: `minValue = Math.Min(a, Math.Min(b, c))` and `maxValue = Math.Max(a, Math.Max(b, c))`

Comment: @JohnAlexiou too easy...

Comment: @JohnAlexiou, now you only need to manage to incorporate three dummy `if`'s ;-)

Comment: @Steve - isn't this what programming is about? Finding easy and obvious solutions to problems.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Of course... in real life you have no such absurd constraints. So I suppose that this a logic exercise more than a real programming problem. So I think that they would also ban the use of Math library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with presumption that first numbers are biggest and smallest. Then check 3 possible cases where presumption was wrong...

```
double n1, n2, n3, biggest , smallest;
Console.Write("First number:  ");
n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Second number: ");
n2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Third number: ");
n3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

biggest = n1;
smallest = n2;

if (n1 < n2 )
{
    smallest = n1;
    biggest = n2;
}
if (n3 < smallest)
{
    smallest = n3;
}
if (n3 > biggest )
{
    biggest = n3;
}
Console.WriteLine("\tMax: {0}", biggest);
Console.WriteLine("\tMin: {0}", smallest);
```

On a side note:
At first sight, the constraint to use only if-statements without 'else' blocks may seem artificial (and maybe absurd), making this problem more of an exercise in logical thinking than coding.
But actually these constraints are relevant on two levels:

- Program style (this is subjective): 'else' blocks increase the code complexity and code with multiple 'if..else..' statements certainly does not help the readability of your code.
- When you consider the generation of optimized, efficient low level (assembly) code, adding an 'else' block to an 'if' statement will result in an extra branch-instruction being emitted as overhead. Not only does this make your binary code slightly larger, branch-instructions are also undesirable in a modern highly pipelined processorcore. A branch can lead to a stall of the pipeline, thus lowering the performance of your code. Of course, branch prediction in the processor goes a long way in avoiding those stalls. But the OP's problem (finding smallest & largest number out of three) is not the easiest situation for branch prediction: which branches will be taken (or not) is highly random in contrast to e.g. the branches constituting a loop.
  An optimizing compiler might eliminate 'else' block, but then again it might not.

So personally, if an 'else' block can be substituted by simpler code, I would prefer to do so (without being too fanatic about it).